# How to install n98-magerun on a docker container

Tags: magento-1.7, docker

I have a Magento 1.7 version running on a container, and I would like to use n98-magerun.

How can install n98-magerun when using a Dockerfile and not docker-compose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your Dockerfile.

```
RUN \
curl -sS -o n98-magerun.phar https://files.magerun.net/n98-magerun.phar &&  \
curl -sS -o n98-magerun.phar.sha256 https://files.magerun.net/sha256.php?file=n98-magerun.phar && \
shasum -a 256 -c n98-magerun.phar.sha256 && \
chmod +x n98-magerun.phar && \
mv n98-magerun.phar /usr/local/bin/n98-magerun.phar
```

Comment: Can you please explain why you're downloading the sha256 because I got it to work (thank you!!!) without downloading it? I ran into issues because I couldn't use [-a] on my CentOS.

Comment: This is only a security feature to verify that the phar file is valid and not a replaced phar file by a man in the middle attack. For a Mac you can use  "gsha256sum".